# Android call Method after rendering a Layout

Tags: java, android

I started programming Android apps. But I have one question. Is it possible to call a method first after the Layout belonging to the Activity has renderd and not at the onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (scroll down a bit for it) to see the hooks that you have. The layout is usually rendered (as in measured, laid-out, etc) when you call `setContentView` inside `onCreate`, but becomes visible on-screen only after `onResume`. Note that `onResume` can be called multiple times, while `onCreate` is only called once.

Answer (score 1):

no it is not possible to call a method first after the Layout belonging to the Activity has renderd. oncreate is start point of your activity. check following link for more information
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // WRITE YOUR CODES HERE
}
```

You can write after rendering works inside the `onStart()`
for deep knowledge visit [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onStart())